# Alea doesnt release memory correctly

Tags: aleagpu

it seems that Alea is not disposing class DeviceMemory2D correctly

my code for checking free memory

```fs
let getFreeMemory () =
    let free = Marshal.AllocHGlobal sizeof<uint64>
    let total = Marshal.AllocHGlobal sizeof<uint64>

    let freePtr = NativeInterop.NativePtr.ofNativeInt<nativeint> free
    let totalPtr = NativeInterop.NativePtr.ofNativeInt<nativeint> total

    CUDAInterop.cuMemGetInfo(freePtr, totalPtr)
    |> cuSafeCall

    let result = NativeInterop.NativePtr.get freePtr 0

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal free
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal total

    uint64 result
```

And here's the code that checks whether there's any leak

```fs
Seq.init 100 (fun _ -> 
        use arr = Gpu.Default.AllocateDevice<float>(1000,1000) 

        getFreeMemory()
        |> printfn "%d"
    )
|> Seq.iter id
```

[image: The outputs]

From the output image, the memory doesn't seem to be disposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the latest beta version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alea/3.0.4-beta3